# Difference between @H and @H[0]

Tags: pointers, delphi, waitformultipleobjects

I have

```
 var H: array of THandle;
```

then in a loop I create multiple threads, and assign thread handles to the elements of H, and then wait on them. Passing @H[0] as the 2nd parameter to WFMO below works.

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(H), @H[0], True, INFINITE) <-- Works
```

But passing @H as below Fails with WAIT_FAILED. GetLastError returns "Invalid Handle".

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(H), @H, True, INFINITE)  <--- Fails.
```

Why is @H different from @H[0] ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Because it is a dynamic array, `H` is already a pointer and it points to the first element, so
2. `@H[0]` is the same as `H` - pointer to the first element
3. and now `@H` is equals to `@@H[0]` - pointer to pointer to the first element.

Comment: Thank you. So, if H was declared as `H: array[0..10] of THandle` then @H and @H[0] would be the same, I suppose. I can check it.

Comment: @Nani Yes, if `H` is a **static array**, than you need to get its address via `@` operator and then `@H` is equals to `@H[0]`.

Comment: You can slso use POINTER(H) to get a pointer to the first element of the dynamic array.